# Retorno de datos int y date como string

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Tengo una tabla que tiene varios campos date e int.

El controlador al momento de hacer store:

```
public function store(DrawRequest $request)
{
    return response(new DrawResource(Draw::create($request->all())))
        ->setStatusCode(201);
}
```

El modelo:

```
  class Draw extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $table = 'draws';

    protected $fillable = [
        'start_date', 'end_date', 'complete_to_time', 'complete_to_date', 'tournament_id', 'calendar_id',
        'state', 'prize_money', 'registration_price'
    ];

    protected $dates = ['start_date', 'end_date','complete_to_date'];

    protected $dispatchesEvents = [
        'created' => DrawCreatedEvent::class,
        'updated' => DrawUpdatedEvent::class,
        'deleted' => DrawDeletedEvent::class,
```

El resource:

```
class Draw extends JsonResource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'success' => true,
            'data' => [
                'success' => true,
                'data' => $this->resource
            ]
        ];
    }
}
```

y al momento de retornar los datos me devuelve todos como string menos el id:

```
{
"success": true,
"data": {
    "success": true,
    "data": {
        "start_date": "2019-10-19 00:00:00",
        "end_date": "2019-10-20 00:00:00",
        "tournament_id": "1",
        "calendar_id": "1",
        "updated_at": "2019-06-10 10:06:55",
        "created_at": "2019-06-10 10:06:55",
        "id": 5
    }
}
```

}

la unica forma de cambiar esto es castear al tipo de dato correcto en el resource, pero es tedioso, haciendo algo como esto:

```
    protected $casts = [
    'tournament_id' => 'integer',
    'calendar_id' => 'integer',
    'prize_money' => 'prize_money',
    'state' => 'boolean'
];
```

Comment: ¿Y cuál es la pregunta?

Comment: Pues según yo la única forma de lograr lo que quieres es utilizar mutators o casts (como ya lo haces). https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-mutators

Answer (score 1):

Lo ideal es siempre en los JsonResource, definir la data como quieres que se muestre, no se debe mostrar todas la propiedades del modelo, porque no siempre utilizas todas.

```
class Draw extends JsonResource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'success' => true,
            'data' => [
                'success' => true,
                'data' => [
                   'tournament_id' => (int) $this->resource->tournament_id,
                   'calendar_id' => (int) $this->resource->calendar_id,
                   // TODO: Incluir restantes...
                ]
            ]
        ];
    }
}
```